# Specify which function was used on string within a map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map of strings that all need to be modified by one of several functions based on some conditions.

My problem is that once I return the map, I need someway to identify which function was used on that specific string. My current idea is to add an identfier at the end of each string so I can check.

Ex. In the case the function "HPV" was used : mystring = mystring + "HPV"

Then on the return end, I can check the end of the string and know which function was used.

Is this an appropriate solution or is there a more efficient way that does not involve checking and modifying every single string?

Comment: Does each method return a String? You could return a `Tuple<String, String>` where the first param is the actual String to return and the second param is a unique identifier for the method.

You can then figure out what method was invoked by looking at the second param of the Tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use an object that can return both the actual String and the identifier of the function that did the work on it.

If the functions that will do the work are all known at compile-time, they can be identified by an enum, otherwise just another String that holds their ID.

Here is a simple suggestion on how to do that:

```java
enum StringModifier {
  HPV, OTHER
}

record ModifiedString(
  String string,
  StringModifier modifier
) {}

main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, String> originalMap = ...
  Map<String, ModifiedString> modifications = transform(originalMap, ...)
}
```

This avoids allocating new Strings and "dirty-ing" them, which can give you trouble later to clean them up as you probably want to make sure you know what the actual result String should look like.